# Minimum number of times needed to cut a cube

Tags: geometry, contest-math, 3d

How many times would I have to cut a large cube to form 64 individual, equally sized smaller cubes?

> To get $4$ equally sized cubes, it would take $3$ cuts. $4^3$ is $64$
> so my guess is $3^3$ which is $27$, is this correct?

Comment: You won't get 4 equal sized cubes with 3 cuts. But maybe you can get 8. :) But maybe that's not the optimal way :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2950625/255730